# Custom Google Spreadsheet Function Returning a Hyperlink or an Existing Formula

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am currently entering hyperlinks in a Google Spreadsheet in the form:

```
=HYPERLINK("http://jira.com/browse/ISSUE-12345","ISSUE-12345")
```

I am duplicating "ISSUE-12345" each time. I would like to create a function JIRA(12345) which gives the same result as the above hyperlink. Is there a way to return a hyperlink in a script, such that something like

```js
function JIRA(jiraNum) {
  // Returns JIRA hyperlink
  var link = ("http://jira.com/browse/ISSUE-"+jiraNum,"ISSUE-"+jiraNum);
  return link;
}
```

would work?

Answer (score 4):

You can alleviate the need to `setForumla` and have to deal with permissions, by setting the the cell value as follows:

```
=HYPERLINK(getJiraTicketLink(12345), getJiraTicketLabel(12345))
```

where `12345` of course can be a *(hidden column-)* neighboring cell instead of a hardcoded string.

Then you create two simple functions akin to the below:

```
var JIRA_BASE_URL = "http://jira.com/";
var JIRA_PROJECT_PREFIX = "ISSUE-";

function getJiraTicketLink(jiraNum) {
  return JIRA_BASE_URL + "browse/" + JIRA_PROJECT_PREFIX + jiraNum;
}

function getJiraTicketLabel(jiraNum) {
  return JIRA_PROJECT_PREFIX + jiraNum;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I struggled with the same, filed a [feature request and received an interesting solution](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2521):

Applied to your situation the following would work.

```
function onEdit(e) {
 // limit to only apply to specific range
  col = e.range.getColumn();
  row = e.range.getRow();        
  if (row > 1 && row < 10 && col == 1) { // A2:A9
    if (e.value != "")
      e.range.setFormula("=HYPERLINK(\"http://jira.com/browse/ISSUE-"+e.value+"\", \"ISSUE-"+e.value+"\")");
  }
}
```

I consider this to be a workaround, but currently it is probably the only way to go.

Comment: Great ! I just had to replace the "," between the 2 parameters of hyperlink formula by ";" to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this: https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2521

It appears that this feature is not available and will not be available.

If you are willing to skip on the text-display 'ISSUE-1234', you can at least return **link** for a working link.

```
function JIRA(jiraNum) {
  var link = 'http://jira.com/browse/ISSUE-' + jiraNum;
  return link;
 }
```

I hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

You can use rich text builder:

```
function onEdit(e){
      var jiraIDColumnID = 1;
      var jiraIDfirstRow = 5;
      var jiraBaseURL = "https://jira.tttttt.com/";
      if (e.value != null && 
          e.value.trim().length != 0 &&
          e.range.getColumn() == jiraIDColumnID && 
          e.range.getRow() >= jiraIDfirstRow ) 
      {
        var richValue = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
          .setText(e.value)
          .setLinkUrl(jiraBaseURL + "browse/" + e.value)
          .build();
        e.range.setRichTextValue(richValue);
      } 
    }
```

Answer (score -4):

No need for a script function:

```
=HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE("http://jira.com/browse/ISSUE-",12345),CONCATENATE("ISSUE-",12345))
```

and if you have your jiraNum in a cell (for example, A2), you can use the cell reference:

```
=HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE("http://jira.com/browse/ISSUE-",A2),CONCATENATE("ISSUE-",A2))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I would like to know how to achieve this with a script function. I do not keep the number in another column (and do not intend to).

Comment: That's even more typing;  What is needed is something simple; a short function such that one can simply enter '=JIRA("ISSUE-1234")' in the cell and have that same cell behave as if =HYPERLINK(url, text) were entered in it.  When one has to do this 400 times, one will appreciate the requirement...